# SSL/TLS certificates that only certain users can use to talk to my server

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, authorization

are there something like SSL/TLS certificates or other equivalents which could allow only certain trusted users (from the internet) who have my server credentials in their browser to access my web server? How to go about doing this method? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Client certificates?

Set your SSL/TLS-server to reject any connection that does not present a valid [Client Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate).

### Related questions

- 2012-05-03: [*Advantages of client certificates for client authentication?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/advantages-of-client-certificates-for-client-authentication)